# Is there a reasonable substitute for nail guns when installing baseboards?

Tags: flooring, baseboard, mdf

What are the alternatives to nail guns? I need to install new `MDF` based baseboards and trims. Buying a new nail gun with air compressor or a battery powered nail-gun is quite costly. I see there is also nail tacker or hammer tackers available. Will they do the job, or they tend to be for other purposes? For example, I'd like to use brad nails 1-1/2"

Comment: My opinion is pneumatic brad nailers are the way to go, you can get a cheap pancake compressor that will run a brad nailer under 60$. That or go back to old school finishing nails a hammer and nail set other than a hammer stapler most of those hammer devices have pros showing them off.  when a consumer purchases they gouge the trim and still need to set the brad, makes me think of the electric hammer I saw advertised a few years back.

Comment: A manual "squeeze"-type brad tacker won't be able to shoot  the length of brads to secure the molding.

Comment: You can rent those tools for a pittance. That's what I'd do.

Comment: I found a brad nailer for $30, and a compressor that comes with an air line for $50. Add a box of nails and we're still under $100. In my profession it'd be unreasonable to *not* own either, but even I don't have a cordless trim nailer.

Comment: @Mazura A cordless trim nailer is the "bees knees" and I'm just a home-owning web developer; no cord, no loud compressor, no hassle :-)

Comment: They're definitely awesome. They're also ~$300.

Comment: @Mazura Holy crikes, which brand? Assuming you already have a battery and charger then the tool alone should be $100 on the cheap side and $250 on the high side. Maybe it's just expensive in your region?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - Well if I was going to get one it wouldn't be on the cheap. And I'm still rocking 18 volt Dewalt, so I'd need all that stuff. Cheapest Dewalt I'm seeing is $200, tool only. High side is $450.

Comment: @Mazura I did say "trim" nailer but I meant to say that I own an 18-gauge brad nailer so that would also affect the price range. I see Dewalt has a framing nailer nowadays which is pretty sweet; just waiting for Team Ridgid to catch up :-). Not that I necessarily need a framing nailer though

Answer (score 4):

You could get something called a [trim screw](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GRK-Fasteners-8-x-1-1-2-in-Star-Drive-Trim-Head-Finish-Screw-100-per-Pack-119724/203525312). They also sell them in [white](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GRK-Fasteners-8-x-2-in-Star-Drive-Trim-Head-White-Trim-Screw-100-Pack-96060/204837639) if you wish to match the color and not cover the hole with putty.

[image: GRK 1.25 inch trim screw]

It sounds like you don't feel comfortable with trim nails as you might damage the surface of the material with your hammer. Quite frankly, that will likely happen if you're a novice.

A brad nailer is great for speed but if you have time then screw in a few trim screws and call it a day.

The only downside is that if you ever need to remove the trim and re-use it then you will likely need to know where to unscrew the screws. I would imagine that pulling the trim off without unscrewing the screws would damage the trim beyond re-use.

Comment: does this work on MDF boards as well? I worry the screws will crush the boards?

Comment: the screws won't crush the mdf boards, just stop once the head of the screw is flush.  Have you looked at possibly renting an electric brad nailer?

Comment: @Mark Yes, they will be excellent for MDF. The heads are so small that they just sink in without damaging the surrounding material. However, if you're worried then test it out on some scrap MDF. I think you will like the end result :)

Comment: You'd want to counterbore for these. If you try and drive them flush you'll have bulging. Pilot for the screw head to its depth, then pilot through the trim to the screw shaft size. Don't pilot the framing.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a nail spinner, it looks like this:

[image]
<sup>Image from somewhere on Pinterest. This particular one is a Vermont American tool (to make finding one easier, not a recommendation or endorsement).</sup>

I used one for many years before my FIL purchased a finish nailer that I can borrow from him when I need it.

You chuck the nail spinner into your drill and drive the nail *most* of the way in, then you finish with a nail set and a hammer.

Slower than a nail gun. Slower than just using a hammer, but much less likely to split the wood (though MDF doesn't really split), and minimizes the potential for damage from a missed hammer blow since you're only hitting the nail set, not the nail itself.

Answer (score 2):

Once upon a time we used hammers.

**Just pre-drill (pilot) for hardened trim nails.**

Hardened trim nails are narrower and stiffer than mild steel nails. I'd use 2" length, which should leave about 1" of penetration into the framing. They'll drive like butter and they'll set nicely. You can even use one of the nails as a drill bit.

**Other tips**

When setting baseboard, nearly all of your nails should be near the top. This keeps the top edge tight and looking professional. Driving nails down low can cause the board to tip into the depression created by drywall sheets or imperfect walls. Find the studs and set one nail in every other one, then backfill on the other studs just where you need to tighten gaps. After that, add a very few nails down low just to keep it from moving.

Also, be sure you understand the reason for and methods of doing [cope joints](https://www.familyhandyman.com/project/how-to-cope-joints/). Inside corners should not be mitered unless you're using fully square (craftsman-style) trim. Cut a hair long and flex into place for a great fit.

Comment: A hammer will do, but it's not very novice-friendly. There's a fair chance you'll end up with a bunch of dents in the soft-ish MDF if you aren't experienced enough. It just takes one blow that's a bit harder than necessary to drive the nail in flush and then dent the surrounding MDF with the excess energy.

Comment: Sure. Every tool has a learning requirement. I can't imagine anyone wanting to do home improvement and _not_ wanting to learn to use a hammer, though.

Comment: Oh yeah, sure, no disagreement there. I just wanted to add a heads-up for the newbies: Be extremely careful with the hammer here, there's no way to get the dents out afterwards. This is certainly not the right job to train your hammer skills.

Answer (score 1):

construction adhesive + nails/hammer would be another option. You could space out the nails less frequently than you would with a nail gun.